# The profile picture of google firebase can not be found after uninstalling the application

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I develop an application through tutorials and old subject of the site, it allows a registration of the user. All this went well until I had them uninstall my application (on BlueStacks), after reinstalling the app the profile picture no longer appears (just a white background).

I wonder what could have cost such a problem? I have already seen several other subjects but not of this type, which is why I allow myself to come and lose you a little of your time. I admit that I am not very good on android studio, so any help will be welcome.

I get my image that way :

```js
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser user;

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
if(sessionManager.isd()){
    String pseudo = sessionManager.getPseudo();
    String id = sessionManager.getId();
    String email = sessionManager.getEmail();

    if(user!=null) {
        Uri image_uri = user.getPhotoUrl();
        user_profile.setImageURI(image_uri);
    }
 }
```

And when registering a new user I proceed as follows:

```js
/*----------For saving image and user name in Firebase Database-------*/
    private void userProfile() {
        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(user != null){
            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .setDisplayName(til_pseudo.getEditText().getText().toString().trim())
                    .setPhotoUri(image_uri).build();
            user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    verifyEmailRequest();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what the user object holds in respect to the url of the photo? Did you check inside firebase to see what the user's photo url is?

Comment: Hello tomerpacific ! Sorry for having time to answer. Exactly in the "database" or in the "storage" I do not see anything registered and I do not understand since before uninstalling the app all that went well even if these spaces was always empty.

Comment: In fact, the storage and the database have always been empty, but it worked perfectly before uninstalling the app.